# Jar dependency for retry task Ant?

Tags: ant

I've looked at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/retry.html and it doesn't list the necessary jars to ensure that the following error doesn't occur:

```
build.xml:80: Problem: failed to create task or type retry
```

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
<retry retrycount="5">
        <javaTask variable="${host}" variable2="${user}" variable3="${pass}"/>
</retry>
```

Comment: What version of Ant are you running?

Comment: I'm currently using 1.7.0.

Answer (score 2):

You need Ant version 1.7.1 or better to utilize `retry`.  Per [the documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/retry.html):

> Retry is a container which executes a single nested task until either: there is no failure; or: its retrycount has been exceeded. If this happens a BuildException is thrown. **Since Apache Ant 1.7.1**